# Compare between exponents

Tags: exponentiation

which one will be larger,

$99^{99}-99^{98}$

or

$99^{98}$

I could not find any exponent properties that will help solving this.

Comment: $99^{98}(99-1) = 99^{98}\cdot 98$ clearly the first one. done

Answer (score 4):

You could use substitution. Let $99^{98}$ be $x$. Then the two choices would be $$99x-x$$ and $$x$$ Now you can obviously see that $99^{99}-99^{98}$ is larger.

Comment: That explains it. Thanks.